# What does "pop the slides" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Protagonist: You want to crash a transport plane? What about the crew?
>
> Mahir: We **pop the slides**, chuck 'em off.

What does "pop the slides" mean?

Source: Christopher Nolan's movie [*Tenet* (2020)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenet_(film))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Slides" here refers to [evacuation slides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evacuation_slide) that you might see on an aircraft. They are used to evacuate people from the aircraft in time of emergency. "Pop the slides" just means to release the slides. "Chuck'em off" means to kick (the crew) off the plane (through the slides).